# multiple elements on expand functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

How change this script to multi elements?:
if click on link (see demo) called: "I'd like expand article on this link" 
this link expand single element NOT all like now.

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/sxXn2/1945/

```
        $(function () {
        $('div.readmore').expander({
            slicePoint: 0,
            expandPrefix:     '',
            expandText: 'Click Here to Read More',
            userCollapseText: 'Hide Text'
        });
        $('.linkclass').click(function () {$(".more-link").click();});
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but it sounds like you only want to expand the article that directly follows the link, correct? If so, you have to trigger the `click` event on the correct element, not all elements with class `more-link`. Have a look at the jQuery documentation to learn about traversal methods: https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `.linkclass` click handler to this one:

```
$('.linkclass').click(function () {
    $(this).next(".readmore").find(".more-link").click();
});
```

What it does: 1). takes the next sibling section with class `.readmore`. 2). searches for `.more-link` within it. 3). triggers click event on correct read more link.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sxXn2/1947/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/sxXn2/1946/
It that how you'd like it work?

It's about that string:

`$('.linkclass').click(function () { $(".more-link").click() });`

$('.more-link') select each link with that class in document. In your case you should go like:

`$(this).next().find(".more-link").click();`